# Why is return error not working in try-catch? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

In the below code, I'm trying to try-catch.

try-catch Function:

```
const updateReturnInformation = async () => {
if (state.isLoading) {
  throw new Error('Errrrrror!!!') // <- It is success working
}

dispatch(actionSetLoading(true))
try {
  await updateReturnAPI(...)
} catch (ex) {
  return ex // <- why not working?
} finally {
  dispatch(actionSetLoading(false))
}
}
```

And, I called this function in another component:

```
...
try {
  await updateReturnInformation()
  navigation.navigate(Routes.Root.Modal.Confirm, {
    title: 'success!',
    buttons: ['OK'],
  })
} catch (ex) {
  navigation.navigate(Routes.Root.Modal.Confirm, {
    heading: 'Error',
    title: ex,
    buttons: ['OK'],
  })
}
...
```

I called updateReturnInformation(), But It working only print 'success!' message.

Also, The console.log will still only print a 'success!' message if an error occurs.

Changing the `return error` of updateReturnInformation () to `throw error` works fine, but I have to only use `return error`.

What's wrong?

Comment: You're not assigning the return value of `updateReturnInformation()` to anything. How can you tell that `return ex` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use `return ex`, then you have to use the return value in the caller, not `catch`.

```
let ex = await updateReturnInformation()
if (ex) {
  navigation.navigate(Routes.Root.Modal.Confirm, {
    heading: 'Error',
    title: ex,
    buttons: ['OK'],
  })
} else {
  navigation.navigate(Routes.Root.Modal.Confirm, {
    title: 'success!',
    buttons: ['OK'],
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Comment: But, it does not working `if (state.isLoading) {
  throw new Error('Errrrrror!!!')
}`.

Answer (score 2):

The `catch()` method returns a Promise and deals with rejected cases only. Try using `reject(error)` and you'll can capture that error upwards.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: Thank you for reference!